# Slider position set to maximum

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to make slider handle position to maximum. I am not asking about the range. Simply by default slider handle is on left side. But I want it on right side(showing the maximum value) in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `Value` to `Maximum` and make sure you set Binding mode as `OneTime` -

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
        Value="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                 Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

OR you can have it in app resources so that it gets applied by default for all sliders -

```
<Style TargetType="Slider">
  <Setter Property="Value"
          Value="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Mode=OneTime}"/>
</Style>
```

---

Other way round is to have your own custom slider class which will always be set to maximum value -

```
public class MySlider : Slider
{
    public MySlider()
    {
        Loaded += (s, e) => Value = Maximum;
    }
}
```

Use in your xaml -

```
<local:MySlider Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
```

where local is namespace of where MySlider class is declared.

Comment: Is it possible with out binding ?

Comment: Notice binding mode is one way only. Otherwise you can explicitly set value to maximum value to hardcoded value `Value="100"`.

Comment: Added with another approach. See if that helps. Moving thumb to right is equivalent to setting value to maximum.

Comment: Which approach not working? Both approaches working at my end. Can you share what have you tried?